# When the reader sees the words "foreshadow" or "omen" does it usually mean good things or bad?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns, synonyms, connotation

I'd like to use a word like "foreshadow", or a word similar to it, as long as the reader will understand what is to come is going to be *good*.

Is the a subjective interpretation of "foreshadow" or "omen" a good thing or a bad thing?

What alternative would mean something positive?

Comment: Related; http://english.stackexchange.com/q/46237

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a word with a similar meaning to foreshadow, but with the connotation of a good outcome, you could use the word *augur*. Whether it's appropriate or not depends on the exact use you want it for, but the word *augur* is indeed generally associated with something good. Consider this Ngram:

[image]

Comment: Also, *augur* is more commonly found in the collocation 'augur well' than with any other words.

Comment: Perhaps we're all becoming more optimistic. I'd always thought that **bode** was pretty much the antonym of **augur**, in that it invariably applies to bad things. But apparently [that's no longer true](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bodes+well%2Cbodes+ill&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). I would just note that **augurs ill** is more common than Peter's alternatives, though still less common than "well".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I just added "ill" to the Ngram. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Among words of its kind, *foreshadow* is one of the most neutral.  Its [synonyms](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=foreshadow&send=Look+it+up) *forebode, threaten* connote problems, but *[foreshadow](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/foreshadow)* itself seems to not do so: "To presage, or suggest something in advance."

I usually think of *[presage](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/presage)* as neutral, i.e. of its "An intuition of a future event; a presentiment" meaning, but I see it also has a usage that may be negative:  "A warning of a future event; an omen".

The words I meant by "words of its kind", above, are synonyms (not all relevant) of *[presage](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=presage)*, *[foretell](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=foretell)*, and *[omen](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=omen)*: *announce, annunciate, anticipate, augur, augury, bode, call, forebode, foreboding, forecast, forerunner, foretell, foretoken, harbinger, herald, indication, omen, portend, portent, predict, premonition, presage, prognostic, prognosticate, promise, prophesy, sign, threat, threaten, warning*.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, foreshadow is a relatively benign term. I don't expect malevolence to come from its usage. It's a simple forecasting of an event that has not yet occurred. ("In retrospect, Ellen's habit of playing teacher as a young girl foreshadowed her career as an English lit professor.")

Omen or portent, for that matter, usually has a connotation of ill-fortune soon to befall someone. ("The black cat crossing one's path is seen as an omen to the superstitious.")

Answer (score 1):

While *foreshadow* and *omen* can apply equally to good or bad situations per their dictionary definitions, I think there's a minor tendency for both to be negative in common usage.  (I think OP has probably seen that too, hence the question.)  Look at the contexts in which they're often used; we talk about a movie *foreshadowing* something (cue ominous music!), usually the turn of events that's going to make things hard for the heroes, or getting a bad feeling when you receive an *omen*.  Not always and not a super-majority of the time, but there's a tendency in my experience (American English).

A neutral word for "providing an indication of something to come" is *telegraph*.  This takes an object: "telegraph a move", "telegraph an aquisition", "carelessly telegraph the 'surprise' party", etc.

Comment: Telegraph is often used in the negative sense, that it makes something that should be a surprise, not a surprise. For example "That film would have been good, but the so-called twist was telegraphed in the first scene"

Answer (score 0):

One can also say a *harbinger* or *talisman* of *good luck* or *fortune*.  These can figuratively be used to refer to any event.

Comment: _Harbinger_ seems even more dire than _foreshadowing_ and _omen_ to me. It's usually associated with doom.

Comment: @Bradd There are at least as many neutral or positive uses of harbinger as bad in titles of Wikipedia articles, and apparently it's not usually associated with doom: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=harbinger+of+good%2C+harbinger+of+bad&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: I'm puzzled as to why you didn't actually include _harbinger of doom_ in that ngram, as it's currently more common than _harbinger of bad._ However, _harbinger of good_ is still more common, and _doom_ appears to be a recent development, so it appears that I was mistaken. Sorry.